# Java: stopping long HTTP operations

Tags: java, http, apache-commons

I'm using Apache Common library for HTTP operations:

```
HttpClient client = getClient();
PutMethod put = new PutMethod(url);
FileRequestEntity countingFileRequestEntity = new FileRequestEntity(file, "application/octet-stream");
put.setRequestEntity(countingFileRequestEntity);
client.executeMethod(put);
put.releaseConnection();
```

I wonder how can safely interrup long HTTP operation. Running it in new thread and stopping it seems to be wrong way. HttpMethodBase has abort() method, but I can't understand how to use it because `client.executeMethod` blocks execution until it complets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to run `executeMethod()` in one thread and call `abort()` from another one.